# Eigen and Dynamic Allocation

Tags: c++, eigen

I have some mathematically computations in C++ that I'm moving to Eigen. Previously I've manually rolled my own `double*` arrays and also used `gsl_matrix` from the GNU Scientific Library.

What confused me was the wording in the [FAQ of Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Talk%3aFAQ#When_does_storage_get_freed_by_Eigen.3F). What does that mean, is it that there's some kind of reference counting and automatic memory allocation going on?

And I just need to confirm that this is still valid in Eigen:

```
// n and m are not known at compile-time
MatrixXd myMatrix(n, m);
MatrixXd *myMatrix2 = new MatrixXd(n, m);

myMatrix.resize(0,0); // destroyed by destructor once out-of-scope
myMatrix2->resize(0,0);
delete myMatrix2;
myMatrix2 = NULL; // deallocated properly
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is valid. However, note that even if you resize the array to `0`, the `MatrixXd` object will still exist, just not the array it contains.

```
{
    MatrixXd myMatrix(n, m); // fine
} // out of scope: array and matrix object released.

{
    auto myMatrix = new MatrixXd(n, m); // meh
    delete myMatrix; // both array and matrix object released
}

{
    auto myMatrix = new MatrixXd(n, m); // meh
    myMatrix->resize(0, 0); // array released
} // out of scope: matrix object leaks
```

Avoid `new` and use automatic storage duration whenever possible. In other cases, use `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: What would be a better way to do this?

Comment: @rightfold could you expand your answer to include use of unique_ptr?